# Возвести число в степень на этапе компиляции

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Как в fasm возвести число в степень на этапе компиляции? Для других действий с числами, например, битового сдвига можно написать  так: `mov ax, 10 shl constant`, но код `mov ax, 10 pow constant`, не компилируется.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, никак нельзя. Вот в [этой таблице](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.4) такой команды как возведение в степень нету.

Comment: @Zealint это понятно, но может, можно написать какой-нибудь макрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал макрос `pow`, получается немного костыльно, но работает:

```
; Параметры макроса: основание, показатель степени (неотрицательное целое число), переменная-приёмник результата
macro pow x, y, result {
    result = 1
    rept y \{
        result = result * x
    \}
}

pow 10, 5, a ; возводим 10 в степень 5, результат кладём в переменную a

dd a ; должно получиться 100000
dd 100000 ; эталонное значение для сравнения
```

Результат компиляции в 16-ричном виде:

```
A0 86 01 00 A0 86 01 00
```

Видим 0186A0h (100000 в десятичной системе) два раза, что и требовалось.

Comment: Спасибо, код действительно рабочий. А можно сделать так, чтобы макрос не сохранял значение в переменную, а непосредственно подставлял значение в ассемблерную инструкцию — как в моём примере?

Comment: @Imieee, просто не получится. В подключаемом файле `win32ax.inc` реализована возможность, например, вызова макроса `invoke` из другого `invoke` и других объявленных там же макросов, но для `mov`, например, это не реализовано. Макрос `allow_nesting` там занимает там 62 строки.

Comment: Если нужно только в `mov`, то придется переопределить `mov`, если еще какие-нибудь `db`, `dw`, `dd`, то придется переопределить и их, чтобы они поддерживали вызов макроса из параметров. Из коробки само работать не будет.

Comment: Нужно не только в `mov`. А макрос такого вида можно реализовать: `p mov ax, 10 pow 5`? То есть вызывается макрос `p`, который для всех аргументов заменяет `[0-9]+ pow [0-9]+` на возведение в степень. Остальные аргументы просто выводит.

Comment: @Imieee, по идее можно, но я не настолько силен в макросах) Можно попробовать на board.flatassmebler.net спросить, думаю, там подскажут.